# Call Graph API from a console app for a Teams chat from a Service Account

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm attempting to make an api that that can be called and can send someone in our organization a chat message in Teams. It appears that this can all be done through the Graph api and after I authenticate as myself the calls to graph appear to work. **My problem is, how do I authenticate my console application as a service user?** I know my code is using the `DeviceCodeCredentialOptions` to get the users credentials and this is requesting the credentials from the user. How do I authenticate my application with out a person actively using it?

I have the code commented out in my example here for the `TokenAcquirerFactory`. I get an error when trying to use that. I suspect I need to get a token somehow for the "application authorization", but I'm not sure how. I found the commented out code in the [Microsoft Documentation for Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=idweb#acquiretokenforclient-api)

Here's what I have so far:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Azure.Identity;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId");
var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret");
var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId");

var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
    .Build();

//var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    ClientId = clientId,
    TenantId = tenantId,
    // Callback function that receives the user prompt
    // Prompt contains the generated device code that user must
    // enter during the auth process in the browser
    DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
};

/*var tokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance();
ITokenAcquirer acquirer = tokenAcquirerFactory.GetTokenAcquirer();
AcquireTokenResult tokenResult = await acquirer.GetTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
string accessToken = tokenResult.AccessToken;*/

var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Chat
{
    ChatType = ChatType.OneOnOne,
    Members = new List<ConversationMember>
            {
                new AadUserConversationMember
                {
                    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
                    Roles = new List<string>
                    {
                        "owner",
                    },
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {
                            "user@odata.bind" , "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('svc_O365_user@mycompany.com')"
                        },
                    },
                },
                new AadUserConversationMember
                {
                    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
                    Roles = new List<string>
                    {
                        "owner",
                    },
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {
                            "user@odata.bind" , "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('My.Name@mycompany.com')"
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
};

var result = await graphClient.Chats.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

When I run the code above it tells me in the command line I have to visit  https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter a code to authenticate. The authentication works but I need to be able to run this without a user. This is the obstacle I'm trying to get around.

Answer (score 0):

If your service account doesn't require a multi-factor authentication then you can use `UsernamePasswordCredential` from `Azure.Identity` NuGet to authenticate against **Microsoft Entra ID** with a simple username and password.

```
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId");
var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId");
// read from some secure place
var serviceUsername = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Username");
var servicePassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Password");
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

var options = new UsernamePasswordCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var userCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(serviceUsername, servicePassword, tenantId, clientId, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userCredential, scopes);
```

In case of enabled MFA, I think that the user interaction is still required.

Comment: When I run this solution I get an error that says: "MsalClientException: Unsupported User Type 'Unknown'. Please see https://aka.ms/msal-net-up. " That page has a code example but it doesn't appear to work either.